# Placeholder in java Script not running

Tags: javascript, html

My code in not working properly.
Could you tell me where is my mistake ?

Here is my code:

**HTML Part**

```
<form name="" id="" method="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><strong>My Form</strong></legend>
            <div class="">
                <label for="name">Name:-</label>
                <input type="text" value="" id="name" />
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <label for="email">Email:-</label>
                <input type="text" value="your email" id="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <label for="companyId">Company Name:-</label>
                <input type="text" value="" id="companyId" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Java Script**

```
var emailField = document.getElementById("email");
        emailField.onfocus = function(){
            if(emailField.value == "your email"){
                emailField.value =="";
            }
        };
        emailField.onblur = function(){
            if(emailField.value ==""){
                emailField.value == "your email";
            }
        };
```

**[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FE4mt/)**

Comment: Did you tried using `placeholder` attribute in `input` tag?

Comment: sorry but i m not using placeholder .

Comment: Not working properly is a bad description. Give an exact error. Also try removing all attributes with an empty values, id="" makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the value using `=` *(assignment operator)*, whereas you are using `==` which is a *comparison operator*

```
emailField.value ="";
```

And

```
emailField.value = "your email";
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FE4mt/3/)

---

Optionally if you want, you can also use `placeholder` attribute, which would save you 11 lines of JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your javascript snippet is that you use `==` instead of `=` for setting the value.

However: what browsers do you need to support? If they're not too outdated you can just use `<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="YOUR PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE">` and don't need any JS. Check [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) for browser support.

Comment: sorry but i m not using placeholder only just used this code ..

Comment: why not? use placeholder for browsers that support it...browsers that don't will simply not show it. then add the js fix. progressive enhancement is your friend

Answer (score 1):

It is because == is a comparison operator , while = is assignment operator. When you give emailField.value == "" , javascript checks whether the value is an empty string, instead of assigning an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You used

```
emailField.value =="";
```

it should be

```
emailField.value ="";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this , it maybe helpful to you

```
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

dude, you're using a comparision operator instead of assignment:

try this:

```
var emailField = document.getElementById("email");
    emailField.onfocus = function(){
        if(emailField.value == "your email"){
            emailField.value ="";
        }
    };
    emailField.onblur = function(){
        if(emailField.value ==""){
            emailField.value = "your email";
        }
    };
```

Modified Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/8DB43/